# WPF layout update issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm trying to implement a treeview with in place editable nodes. I've managed to get this working but now I would like the following behavior: when the user wants to add a new sub item he right clicks on a node, selects 'add' from the context menu and the new node is added with the new treenode in editmode, so that when he starts typing he is effectively editing the new treenode. Similar to the windows explorer 'add new folder' behavior. There seems to be a tiny glitch in my implementation but I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong. The new node gets added but when i start typing nothing happens, if I hit an arrow button I can start typing in the textbox. It is as if the focus is not there.

This is the treeview in my mainwindow:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildNodes}">
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localvm:TreeViewItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Style>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <localuc:EditableTreeViewItem Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Tag="{Binding}" IsInEditMode="{Binding IsInEditMode, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </localuc:EditableTreeViewItem>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

This is the usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.EditableTreeViewItem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JLGAutomation.Designer.UserControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         x:Name="MyUserControl">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=MyUserControl, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:EditableTreeViewItem}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" 
             Visibility="Collapsed"
             x:Name="TextBox"/>
</Grid>
```

and it's code behind:

```
public partial class EditableTreeViewItem : UserControl
{
    public EditableTreeViewItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(EditableTreeViewItem));

    public bool IsInEditMode
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(IsInEditModeProperty);
        }
        set
        {

            SetValue(IsInEditModeProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsInEditModeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsInEditMode",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(EditableTreeViewItem),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsInEditModeChanged)));

    private static void OnIsInEditModeChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            (source as EditableTreeViewItem).BeginEdit();
        }
        else
        {
            (source as EditableTreeViewItem).EndEdit();
        }
    }

    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        IsInEditMode = true;
        TextBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        Keyboard.Focus(TextBox);
        TextBox.SelectAll();
    }

    public void EndEdit(bool cancel = true)
    {
        TextBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        IsInEditMode = false;
        if (!cancel)
        {
            var bindingExpr = TextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            if (bindingExpr != null)
            {
                bindingExpr.UpdateSource();
            }
        }
    }
```

I think the source of the problem might be in the `BeginEdit` method. `OnIsInEditModeChanged` is called from the viewmodel's `Add` command. Subsequentely `BeginEdit` is called but when I set a breakpoint on the line `Keyboard.Focus(TextBox);` the TextBox is not visible. I suspect that this causes the `Focus` to not work correctly. I'v been playing with `TextBox.ApplyTemplate`, `TextBox.InvalidateVisual`, etc but no difference. Anyone has a clue?

Edit:
This is how it looks at first:
[image]

And after clicking the right button the cursor appears in the box:
[image]

At no time all text is selected, but it is clearly the textbox.

Comment: I think textblock is covering textbox, hide textblock when you make textbox visible.

Comment: No, that's not the case, see the edit I made to the question. The textbox is shown but not focussed (grey border), then gets focus (blue border)